# Cannot infer an array type with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is my code:

```
interface ItemA{
  x:number
  y:string
}

interface ItemB{
  z:boolean
}

interface Data{
  a:ItemA[]
  b:ItemB[]
  bool:boolean
}

type ItemType=keyof Data&('a'|'b')

function f<K extends ItemType>(data:Data,key:K):void{
  type T=Data[K] extends (infer TT)[]?TT:never
  const values:T[]=data[key]

  values.forEach(
    (t:T):void=>{
      console.log(t)
    }
  )
}
```

I'd like `T` to be `ItemA` when `key` is `'a'` and `ItemB` when it's `'b'`. In this way, `values` could be of type `ItemA[]` or `ItemB[]`. How could I achieve this?

I'm getting this TypeScript error:

```
20:9 Type 'ItemA[] | ItemB[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
  Type 'ItemA[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
    Type 'ItemA' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Comment: What's the point of `type ItemType=keyof Data&('a'|'b')`? You might as well just use `'a'|'b'`, or you could do something like `Exclude<keyof Data, "bool">` for better semantics.

Comment: You're right. It was just to let developers know `ItemType` is a property of `Data`, but it could be removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
interface ItemA{
  x:number
  y:string
}

interface ItemB{
  z:boolean
}

interface Data{
  a: ItemA[]
  b: ItemB[]
  bool: boolean
}

type ItemType = 'a' | 'b';

function f(data: Data, key: ItemType): void
{
  type T = Data[typeof key]
  const values: T = data[key]
  values.forEach(
    (t: ItemA | ItemB) => {
      console.log(t)
    }
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjk67N)

Comment: Thanks, it's working!